# Hadoop: Where does the job first execute before the map tasks?

Tags: architecture, hadoop

This is a typical `main` method of a Hadoop Job:

```
public class MyHadoopJobDriver extends Configured implements Tool {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new MyHadoopJobDriver(), args);
    System.exit(exitCode);
  }
  ...

}
```

When I run this job `hadoop MyHadoopJobDriver`, **Is the code above executing in its own JVM on the task tracker?** Then once the job is scheduled, the map tasks are distributed to the task trackers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, usually.  Note that if you "Debug -> as Java Application" that class in Eclipse then you can use the debugger for testing, setting breakpoints, etc.  Note Note that even if you run the driver class and the mapper/reducer in Eclipse, you still need hadoop running on your machine in support of HDFS.

Comment: Why "usually"? Can I not count on this happening? I need to host a sequence generator for my job and am considering just housing that on the JobTracker and just launching it as a daemon from within my job.

Comment: Sorry. meant to say that that does always happen.  Having said that, if you run it in Eclipse (as I do for dev/testing) then the driver class does not run on the job tracker, but in Eclipse.

Comment: Actually, I made a mistake, I meant to ask if this runs on the "jobtracker", not on one of the "tasktrackers". Can you clarify where this is run exactly?